# How to call a method(function) to a form2 which is written in form1 in c#.net?

Tags: c#, methods, call

Of course there are many answers for this question,though,I got no clear Idea for my problem.
I'm working on Visual Studio.I have 2 forms as one is weeklyGVadminview and dailyGVadminview..
I wrote a function(method) in dailyGVadminview which is needed now in another form.....
I'm adding my code here..Any ansers will be appreciated in advance thanks.

```
namespace weeklyattendance
{
public partial class dailyGvAdminview : Form
{
    public dailyGvAdminview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void datechanges()
    {
    string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    string query = "select count(Employee_id) from employee_details";
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
    object result =cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    txttotalstaff.Text = (result.ToString());

    cn.Close();
}
}
}
```

Form2 code as follows

```
namespace weeklyattendance
{
public partial class weeklyGvAdminView : Form
{
    public weeklyGvAdminView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
 private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //here I want to call that function or method
    }
}
```

Comment: you can create object of dailyGvAdminview and call that function.

Comment: Pull the method into its own class, and then call the class form both forms...

Answer (score 0):

You can create object of dailyGvAdminview and call for that try below code :-

```
namespace weeklyattendance
{
public partial class weeklyGvAdminView : Form
{
    public weeklyGvAdminView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
 private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var form1 = new dailyGvAdminview();
       //// call function using this instance
    }
}
```

If you want to access method from outside then make it to Public as shown below :-

```
 public string DateChanges()
    {
    }
```

Comment: should be given public to method?? or no need ?? @neel

Comment: Yes if you want to access it from outside make that method to Public @ShivaDebrown

Answer (score 0):

So I would just create a new class and put the method on that class:

```
public class DbHandler
{
    public string DateChanges()
    {
        string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        var connectionstring =                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        string query = "select count(Employee_id) from employee_details";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        var result = result.ToString();

        conn.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then in your classes do this:

```
var dbHandler = new DbHandler();
var result = dbHandler.DateChanges();
```

I would try and follow some conventions as well. Makes it easier for other programmers to follow what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really GLOBAL and easy solution do this, first you make a static class.

```
namespace weeklyattendance
{

    public static class Obj
    {
        public static dailyGvAdminview globalDaily;
    }
}
```

Then in your initialize or onLoad code where you create this class just write

```
Obj.globalDaily = this;
```

Now you can access this class anywhere in your program with Obj.globalDaily, you can also add whatever else you want in there and access it like that